# Find string in each file. If it exists don't append. If it doesn't exist, append

Tags: powershell

The below script will test a path. If path is found it will loop through each text file and append a string. Someone kindly helped me get to this point.

What I still can't figure out is how to check if string exists. If it exists, move on. And if it doesn't exist, add it.

I've tried variations of get-content. I just don't know how to implement it to cycle through each text file until it's all checked.

```
    # Check to see if AWP is actually installed

    $awpPath = "C:\Program Files\Middleware\Card"
    $aWPExists = Test-Path $awpPath
    $toAppend = "
    library=C:\Program Files\Middleware\middleware.dll
    name=PKCS 11 Middleware
    "

    # If AWP Exists copy the pkcs11.txt file to all Firefox Profiles found.

    $pKCSFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\pkcs11.txt'

    If ($aWPExists -eq $True) {
        Write-Log "AWP Exists and module wasn't found in the pkcs11.txt file. Copying pkcs11.txt to all firefox profiles"

        ForEach ($file in ($pKCSFiles))  {
            $toAppend | Out-File -Append $file -Encoding 'Ascii'


        }
    }
    else {

        Write-Log "AWP doesn't seem to be installed. Please install  before activating this module."
        Exit-Script ExitCode 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
# Check to see if AWP is actually installed

$awpPath = "C:\Program Files\Middleware\Card"
$aWPExists = Test-Path $awpPath
$toAppend = "
library=C:\Program Files\Middleware\middleware.dll
name=PKCS 11 Middleware
"

# If AWP Exists copy the pkcs11.txt file to all Firefox Profiles found.

$pKCSFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\pkcs11.txt'

If ($aWPExists -eq $True) {
    Write-Log "AWP Exists and module wasn't found in the pkcs11.txt file. Copying pkcs11.txt to all firefox profiles"

    ForEach ($file in ($pKCSFiles))  {
        If ((get-content $file -tail 2) -notmatch "PKCS 11") {
            $toAppend | Out-File -Append $file -Encoding 'Ascii'
        }

    }
}
else {

    Write-Log "AWP doesn't seem to be installed. Please install Oberthur Authentic web pack before activating this module."
    Exit-Script ExitCode 1
}
```

Also your script is only appending the pkcs11.txt files not all text files as you're asking

The following code is identical to above, but instead reads the entire file for verification instead of just the end of the file.

```
# Check to see if AWP is actually installed

$awpPath = "C:\Program Files\Middleware\Card"
$aWPExists = Test-Path $awpPath
$toAppend = "
library=C:\Program Files\Middleware\middleware.dll
name=PKCS 11 Middleware
"

# If AWP Exists copy the pkcs11.txt file to all Firefox Profiles found.

$pKCSFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\pkcs11.txt'

If ($aWPExists -eq $True) {
    Write-Log "AWP Exists and module wasn't found in the pkcs11.txt file. Copying pkcs11.txt to all firefox profiles"

    ForEach ($file in ($pKCSFiles))  {
        If ((get-content $file -raw) -notmatch "PKCS 11") {
            $toAppend | Out-File -Append $file -Encoding 'Ascii'
        }

    }
}
else {

    Write-Log "AWP doesn't seem to be installed. Please install web pack before activating this module."
    Exit-Script ExitCode 1
}
```

Last and final option which is most logically sound. It forces it to find the string. And if it doesn't it will append it. Before it was forcing it to NOT find the string. And since the file has multiple lines, it still succeeded.

```
# Check to see if AWP is actually installed

$awpPath = "C:\Program Files\Middleware\Card"
$aWPExists = Test-Path $awpPath
$toAppend = "
library=C:\Program Files\Middleware\middleware.dll
name=PKCS 11 Middleware
"

# If AWP Exists copy the pkcs11.txt file to all Firefox Profiles found.

$pKCSFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\pkcs11.txt'

If ($aWPExists -eq $True) {
    Write-Log "AWP Exists and module wasn't found in the pkcs11.txt file. Copying pkcs11.txt to all firefox profiles"

    ForEach ($file in ($pKCSFiles))  {
        If (!((get-content $file) -match "PKCS 11")) {
            $toAppend | Out-File -Append $file -Encoding 'Ascii'
        }

    }
}
else {

    Write-Log "AWP doesn't seem to be installed. Please install web pack before activating this module."
    Exit-Script ExitCode 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Robert. Sorry I should have clarified that i am only interested in searching within any file named pkcs11.txt. So under each user's firefox profile, i want the script to search for a string inside the pkcs11.txt file. If string exists, do nothing. If it doesn't exist, append.

I have tried the above suggestion and it seems to just append the $toAppend string again and again. Any ideas?

Comment: Change tail 1 to tail 5 or something. You might be hitting enter on the last line causing it to read a blank line. I would remove the enter after you middleware or change the -tail to 2. I have corrected my suggested code

Comment: Should that string be at the end of the file as you're doing? Or can it be anywhere in the file?

Comment: It can be anywhere in the file. But tail 2, did the trick! Thanks Robert. You're a legend!

Comment: If it is anywhere in the file -tail 2 will only check the end. However not using it will demand a full file read. So if they're long files it will slow the script down dramatically

Comment: A full file read will be more suitable. The location of the module could be at the start, middle or end. Presumably tail 1 is better then? Thankfully the files will never be larger than 50 lines or so and there is likely to be less than 10 profiles on each pc.

Comment: just remove "-tail 1" i'll add an example to the main answer now.

Comment: I forgot -tail 1 etc.. brings it to one or 2 lines. Change the get-content to -raw will force it to search all or none. Instead of per line. Thus it will not pass as true. I'll add a third option. Which is probably more logically sound.